# How to restore database in CodeIgniter?

Tags: database, codeigniter, restore, mysql-backup

I don't know how to write code to restore the .sql file whick backup from database using codeigniter. What should I do in controller to be able to restore it?
I just create a form to select .sql file like this:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>main/reStore" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p>Select Database:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="file" name="database"></p>
        <p>Restore Database:&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Restore">
    </form>
```

and don't know what to do in controller

```
function reStore(){
     $this->load->database();

}
```

Comment: [this will helpful](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/)

Comment: You this to [manager your db](http://www.adminer.org/), it can do everything including backups and restore.

Answer (score 1):

I used this code

```
function restore_data()
{
    $folder = FCPATH;
    $folder = str_replace('\\', '/', $folder);  
    $path = $folder.'folder name of the .sql file/';
    $sql_filename = 'file name.sql';

    $sql_contents = file_get_contents($path.$sql_filename);
    $sql_contents = explode(";", $sql_contents);

    foreach($sql_contents as $query)
    {

        $pos = strpos($query,'ci_sessions');
        var_dump($pos);
        if($pos == false)
        {
            $result = $this->db->query($query);
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get an idea from this,may it helps you.

```
public function db_backup()
{
       $this->load->dbutil();   
       $backup =& $this->dbutil->backup();  
       $this->load->helper('file');
       write_file('your_file_path/your_DB.zip', $backup); 
}
```

Comment: The opposite of a restore?

Comment: @Urasquirrel kindly what do mean by "opposite of a restore"...

Comment: I misunderstood, the question. My apologies friend.